# SPF-Record for gmail: some sent mails are rejected

Tags: gmail, spf

We use gmail together with our own domain since 3 years and configured it once right, everything worked fine. Mostly.

But recently, some mails (< 2%) will sometimes being rejected of the destination mail server because of SPF-Issues:

> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   xxxxxx.de by xxxxxxx.de. [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 550 xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx is not
>   allowed to send mail from xxxxxx.com

This is the SPF-Record we have configured as TXT Record in DNS:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx -all
```

Is there something wrong? Last document changes in googles docs are speaking about slightly different settings:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Instead of blind changes without any understanding around the more detailled topic i want to ask around, if our spf-record could be outdated or completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only using Google Apps for Work to send email then yes - your SPF record is wrong.  The correct SPF record for this case is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

If you are also sending emails from your web server directly or from other third party services you will likely need to add additional directives to your SPF record.